# Merge dicts of arbitrary depth in Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

How can I **recursively** merge dicts in Jinja2 without having to define a custom filter?

So

```
  { a: { b: 'ab', d: 'ad'          } }
+ { a: { b: 'aX',          e: 'ae' } }
```

becomes

```
  { a: { b: 'aX', d: 'ad', e: 'ae' } }
```

I'm migrating some Mako-templates to Jinja2. With Mako I could simply use a small python-code snippet doing this for me... The reason I cannot use a custom filter is, that I simply cannot register custom filters in the template engine as I cannot directly access it.

Comment: "cannot register custom filters" as in you don't have control of the template engine, they just provide you with a choice of Mako or Jinja and you write whatever you want as long as it is valid Mako / Jinja code?

Comment: Correct. I'm not in control of the template engine, so I cannot extend it in any way. But I can feed it whatever is considered valid Jinja2 Code.

Comment: Do you have access to the [expression statement `do`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#expression-statement)?

Comment: Yes, I do have 'do' :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem:

```
{%- macro deep_merge(a, b): %}
  {%- for k,v in b.items(): %}
    {%- if v is not defined: %}
      {%- do a.pop(k) %}
    {%- else: %}
      {%- if v is mapping: %}
        {%- if a[k] is not mapping: %}
          {%- do a.update({ k: { } }) %}
        {%- endif %}
        {%- do deep_merge(a[k], v) %}
      {%- else: %}
        {%- do a.update({ k: v }) %}
      {%- endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {%- endfor %}
{%- endmacro %}

{%- do deep_merge(a, b) %}
```

This snippet of Jinja2-Code recursively merges `b` into `a`, overriding duplicate keys (`b` takes precedence) and removing keys from `a` that are set to `null` in `b`.

Comment: I hope they make a `combine_recursive` filter or something to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but it sounds like your situation is a bit [Abby Normal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH97lImrr0Q):

```
{# Untested code - may not work #}
{% macro merge(destination) %}
{% for provider in varargs %}
    {% for key, value in provider.items() %}
        {% if value is mapping %}
            {% set intermediate = {} %}
            {% do merge(intermediate, destination.get(key, {}), value) %}
            {% do destination[key] = intermediate %}
        {% else %}
            {% do destination[key] = value %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
{% set result = {} %}
{% do merge(result, first_values, second_values) %}
{# result is now the merger of first_values and second_values #}
```

Comment: Thank's for your reply. As you see in my answer above, I already found a similar solution. Although, I now see some things I could improve :)

Comment: Glad I could help - when I saw you had an answer I was tempted to delete this one, but I figured providing an alternate approach might be helpful :-)

Comment: Ye, alternatives are always good :) Although I could not get your's to work, as the `{%- do dict[key] = value %}` statements do not seem to work for me: `Jinja syntax error: expected token 'end of statement block', got '='`. That's why I used `dict.update()` in my solution.